# Decrement at Regular Intervals in Java

Tags: java, timer

I'm writing an application in Java, but need to know how to subtract from a variable once every second. What's the easiest way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The "meta-question" that I'd have is what the actual requirement is.  Number of seconds since a particular point in time is easy to calculate without a background thread... and this can then be converted into an on the fly calculation of startValue - numberOfSeconds.  And you won't lose decrements if your timer happens to not fire for some reason.

Comment: The question requires a timer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of [the very Java class you need to use](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to do repeating operations is already sitting there in one of your tags! ;)

Comment: How amusing, and yet rude. I will look it up.

Comment: Sorry, no rudeness intended! Just trying to keep it loose.

Comment: Rude is a bit relative to culture.  In my household or most of the online technical circles I'm in, this response would've gotten a laugh from everyone, including the questioner.

Comment: What's funny is that I often do intend to be sharp, but not on this occasion... I guess I got stuck that way.

Comment: Helpful answer, +1. I saw no rudeness.

Answer (score 5):

While the `Timer` class will work, I recommend using a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead.

While their usage is extremely similar, `ScheduledExecutorService` is newer, more likely to receive ongoing maintenance, fits in nicely with other concurrent utilities, and might offer better performance.

Comment: It's nice to learn about the ScheduledExecutorService, for which +1. However, I'd ask to see evidence that the one is going to be better maintained than the other.

Answer (score 2):

```
class YourTimer extends TimerTask
{
  public volatile int sharedVar = INITIAL_VALUE;

  public void run()
  {
    --sharedVar;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Timer timer = new Timer();

     timer.schedule(new YourTimer(), 0, 1000);
     // second parameter is initial delay, third is period of execution in msec
  }
}
```

Remeber that `Timer` class is not guaranteed to be real-time (as almost everything in Java..)

Comment: You need to make the sharedVar volatile, since the timer runs in a different thread as the program that reads it.

Comment: Noone is reading it actually. However by a matter of principle that' s right.. it should be volatile because otherwise it can be cached by threads (losing synchronization)

Comment: Use `scheduleAtFixedRate()` rather than `schedule()` to overcome the "not real-time" problem.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve? I would not try relying on the timer to properly fire exactly once per second. I would simply record the start time, and whenever a timer fires, recalculate what the value of the variable should be. Here's how I would do it...

```
class CountdownValue {
  private long startTime;
  private int startVal;

  public CountdownValue(int startVal)
  {
     startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public int getValue()
  {
     return startVal - (int)((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no such method as `getCurrentTimeMillis()`. At any way, if you're trying to reinvent the `java.util.Timer`, rather use `nanoTime()` than `currentTimeMillis()` as it has much better accuracy.

Comment: I'm not trying to reinvent the timer. I'm trying to get something that will work more reliably on a heavily loaded system (i.e. you won't have incorrect values for a few hundredths of a second while the timer is waiting for a timeslice).

Comment: Also, good catch on the getCurrentTimeMillis typo. fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a java.util.Timer to create a TimerTask.